# Status Code 500 when trying to restart. Restart after installing plugins option is gone

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We moved Jenkins to another server and after the move, I no longer have the option to "Restart after installing plugins".  The words are there but the checkbox is gone.  When I try /restart in the URL, I get the verify option and after clicking 'Yes' I get a Status Code 500 error.

This is a Linux installation.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: hudson.lifecycle.RestartNotSupportedException: Failed to obtain the command line arguments of the process
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:615)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:658)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:487)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:164)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:47)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:215)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: hudson.lifecycle.RestartNotSupportedException: Failed to obtain the command line arguments of the process
    at hudson.lifecycle.UnixLifecycle.verifyRestartable(UnixLifecycle.java:98)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.restart(Jenkins.java:3151)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doRestart(Jenkins.java:3122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:573)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.jna.Native.open(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:236)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:366)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:351)
    at com.sun.akuma.CLibrary.<clinit>(CLibrary.java:89)
    at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.resolvePID(JavaVMArguments.java:126)
    at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.ofLinux(JavaVMArguments.java:114)
    at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.of(JavaVMArguments.java:104)
    at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.current(JavaVMArguments.java:92)
    at hudson.lifecycle.UnixLifecycle.<init>(UnixLifecycle.java:54)
    at hudson.lifecycle.Lifecycle.get(Lifecycle.java:93)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.restart(Jenkins.java:3150)
    ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some Jenkins configuration info,
or that the owner of the files under 'jenkins' folder is different than the 'jenkins' user
(assuming you run Jenkins as user 'jenkins').

Suggest the following:

- Backup your Jenkins repository 
  (usually sitting under the 'jenkins' user directory)
- Re-install Jenkins from fresh
- See that everything works on the clean installation 
  (install plugins, restart, ...)
- Copy the repository from the backup you did
- Make sure the owner of all files is your current 'jenkins' user 
  (again - assuming you run Jenkins as user 'jenkins')
- Try to restart Jenkins and see how goes

Comment: Thats not realy the answer you want to hear when the server is 800km away… DAMM.

Comment: @Martin, I'm sure you can find your way in, without leaving your desk